# PHP : How to get the lowest array value together of the key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a an array and I need to get the lowest value together of key. Because i need to check if the value has contain the right key or not

```
 Array ( 
      [120] => 97.00 
      [132] => 92.67 
      [124] => 72.33 
      [131] => 49.67 
      [129] => 25.00 
      [127] => 25.00 //<--Get the value and this key
  )
  //This array already sorted, no need to sort just get the last value and key
```

How can i get the lowest value 25.00 together the key [127]

```
 $array = array (

      "120" => 97.00 
      "132" => 92.67 
      "124" => 72.33 
      "131" => 49.67 
      "129" => 25.00 
      "127" => 25.00 

  );

  print_r(min($array)); //<--displaying only the value but not the key
```

The output should be like

```
127 - 25.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array (
      "120" => 97.00, 
      "132" => 92.67,
      "124" => 72.33,
      "131" => 49.67,
      "129" => 25.00,
      "127" => 25.00 

  );
    // point the last element of the element and fetch value to $value
    $value= (end($array));
    // fetch key
    echo "key : ". key($array);
    echo "value :".$value;
```

Comment: This assumes the array will always be in that order and new elements will not be added. It should be sorted first.

Comment: how can you say that have you tested it .... hummm if yes plese show me the result.... otherwise just upvote it? #systematical

Comment: Stupid site wouldn't let me take away my upvote. Only lets me downvote. I guess I'll not be a dick and leave it upvoted. But the code makes an assumption about the order of the elements always being static, which is rarely true. Add another element to end of your array with a very high value and it falls apart immediately.

Comment: no man... i claim that if you sort array either in ascending or descending order you will never get the result provided in question, please try... if you get result as above i will delete my answer ....#systmatical

Answer (score 4):

```
$array=array("120" =>97.00 ,"132"=>92.67,"124"=>72.33 ,"131"=>49.67,"129"=>29.00,"127"=> 25.00);
//get minimum value from array
 $minvalue=(min($array));
 echo "Min Value= ".$minvalue;
//get key of minimum value from array
 $key = array_search($minvalue, $array);
  echo "Key of Min Value".$key;
// make new associative array
$newarray = array($key => $minvalue ); 
  print_r($newarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using asort and then get the key and value of first element

```
//using asort will preserve key value pair sort will happen on value
asort($urarray);
foreach($urarray as $k=>$val){
   //read the first element and break
   echo $k.' - '.floatval($val);
   break;
}
```

For more information on asort read this [php asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

Answer (score -1):

PHP manual loaded with good stuff.

Sort: http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Current: http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

Key: http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

```
<?php
 $array = array (
      "120" => 97.00 ,
      "132" => 92.67 ,
      "124" => 72.33 ,
      "131" => 49.67 ,
      "129" => 25.00 ,
      "127" => 25.00 
  );
asort($array);
$key = key($array);
$value = current($array);
echo "$key - $value"; 
?>
```

You can also use arsort() then do array_pop(). Depends on which direction you want to go.